# Nservicebus Audit Service

Tags: nservicebus

I am trying to create a audit log service using nservicebus.Since i need to make the application without recompiling i found (http://tech.dir.groups.yahoo.com/group/nservicebus/message/9416)it is good to hook OnTransportMessageReceived event.Also i need to store the message body of the incoming message as well.
Could you please let me know how can i achieve?
I tried the following now Create a handler which Handles IMessage

```
public class AuditLogMessagehandler : IHandleMessages<IMessage>
    {
        public IBus Bus { get; set; }

        public ITransport Transport { get; set; }

        public AuditLogMessagehandler()
        {           
        }      

        public void Handle(IMessage message)
        {
            string returnAddress = Bus.CurrentMessageContext.ReturnAddress;
            string id = Bus.CurrentMessageContext.Id;

            string messageType = message.GetType().Name;
            IMessage[] messages = new IMessage[1];
            messages[0] = message;
            MessageSerializer ser = new MessageSerializer();

            Stream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
            ser.Serialize(messages, memoryStream);
            memoryStream.Flush();
            memoryStream.Close();
        }
    }
```

It required the dll to be copied to the bin folder.But i am not getting the message bdoy threre,Also please let me know at what point or how can i hook to OnTransportMessageReceived

Thanks in advance,
Ajai

Answer (score 2):

NServicebus has auditing out of the box. See the following link:

http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/operations/auditing

This will take a copy of the message and move it to an audit Q. From there you can read the audit q and copy the messsage to file, move into a DB. what ever you want.

Does that make sense?

Dave

Comment: http://tech.dir.groups.yahoo.com/group/nservicebus/message/9416 can you please look the above link